# How can I style a class which does not have a parent class?

Tags: css, sass

How can I style all tags with `btn` which isn't in a tag with `btn-group`?

Here is an example of the `HTML`:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">I don't want to style this</button>
</div>
<button class="btn">I want to style this</button>
```

I'm hoping for a `CSS` or `SCSS` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS has no „parent selector” or similiar.

I'd overwrite `.btn-group .btn` styles to undo changes made to `.btn`.

You could try using the [`:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Examples) (like `:not(.btn-group) .btn`), but I'd be surprised if that applied.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't try the opposite. On your css write a class for your .btn and after this write your styles for .btn-group>.btn to overwite the btn without parent!With the symbol > you apply the styles for your direct child selector.So only the btn inside btn-group will change

Comment: So I should "unset" all the properties I add in the first .btn class?

Comment: What do you mean "unset". If some properties have different values you can write the new values you want inside btn-group>.btn

Comment: applying your idea:

`.btn { color: green; } .btn-group > .btn { color:unset; }`